# How do I select changesets to merge that are attached to work items?

Tags: merge, branch, changeset, workitem

I have a set of work items that are completed and I am ready to move their changes to our production branch. Is it possible to find the changesets that are attached to them and selectively merge them with the target branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easily is the short answer.

Currently there is no real link between work items and code promotion.  You can associate a changeset with a work item on check-in (or indeed at any time), but that is about as far as things go.

Basically you would have to do this by hand using the provided UI in Visual Studio (i.e. look up the work items, get the changeset ID's and then do (possibly several) merges by selecting the appropriate changeset ranges.  If this is a regular way of working then you could write a program in .NET that used the [Microsoft TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) to talk to the work item tracking component to get the changesets required and then either did the merges programatically or kicked off the command line client ([tf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx)) to bring up appropriate UI for the merges.

Sorry it's not a more helpful answer.  I know that the team at Microsoft have heard this scenario a few times now however I've not heard of any plans to have it better supported "out the box" in the current or the next release of TFS.  That said, there are a lot of improvements to the branching ad merging stuff in TFS2010 so it is possible that something is/will be in there that might help you.  It may be worth you logging some feedback on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio for this feature if it is important to you.

Good luck,

Martin.